# Magento 2.1 update special price dates programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, price, special-price

I have a problem updating the special price dates of a simple product.
I've tried 2 versions of code, but without results. In both cases the special price will be update, but no affect to the start and end dates.

**Version 1**

```
$set_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($idSimpleProduct);
$set_product->setSpecialPrice(120.00); // this work
$set_product->setSpecialFromDate('1-1-2018'); //also tried with d/m/Y, m/d/Y, Y-m-d
$set_product->setSpecialToDate('2-2-2018');
$set_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($set_product, 'special_price');
$set_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($set_product, 'special_from_date');
$set_product->getResource()->saveAttribute($set_product, 'special_to_date');
$set_product->save();
```

**Version 2**

```
$set_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($idSimpleProduct);
$set_product->setCustomAttributes(array(
            'special_from_date' => date("m-d-Y", strtotime($promoFromDate)), 
            'special_to_date' => date("m-d-Y", strtotime($promoToDate)), 
            'special_price' => $promoPrice
       )
);
$set_product->save();
```

Where I wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct date format is:

```
$product1->setSpecialFromDate(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Taken from \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\Eav\SourceTest::testReindexMultiselectAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick -:

```
$dateValue = '2022-04-08'

$value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateValue));

/* Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository */
$product = $this->productRepository->get($sku, false, 0);

$product->setSpecialFromDate($value);

$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Solution it may work

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->load($productId);

 $product->setName('Some new name for the product')
               ->setSpecialFromDate($product->getSpecialFromDate());

assuming that this = YYYY-MM-DD
           ->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true)
           ->setSpecialToDate($product->getSpecialTODate())
           ->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true)
           ->save();
```